# Send upload image and text to the url (Server) in JSON Format Android

Tags: android, image, post, text, server

i am in trouble ... I have 1 edittext and 2 button , one for post and one for upload camera image and show image in imageview.My code having no errors but when i click on post button the image and text are not shown on the server please check the code I am a newbie so i dont recognise where i missing the code. Thank you in Advance.

This is my PostActivity.java :

```
public class PostActivity extends Activity
{public static final String TAG="url";
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

    TextView submit;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    InputStream is;

    EditText content;
    ImageView imageView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plus);

        submit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button7);

        content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new MainTest().execute();
            }
        });

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new     Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
    public void postImageData() {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.holder);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://blackispink.com/apis/add_post.php?title="
                    + content.getText().toString() + "&content=" + content.getText().toString() + "&cat_id=760" +"&user_id=21");
            Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postRequest);
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

/* example for setting a HttpMultipartMode */
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg");
                builder.addPart("key", bab);
                builder.addPart("key4", new StringBody(content.getText().toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                builder.addPart("key1", new StringBody(content.getText().toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                builder.addPart("key2", new StringBody("21", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                builder.addPart("key3", new StringBody("760", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);

            }
            postRequest.setEntity((HttpEntity) builder);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
    public class MainTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PostActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            postImageData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // data=jobj.toString();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put this `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and tell us if there is an exception..

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to Base 64 and send this to your server .

Answer (score 0):

For the text, you can use the lines of codes

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1","content 1"));
                    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "content 2"));
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
                    try {
                        entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");

                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url link");
                        httppost.setEntity(entity);
                        try {
                            client.execute(httppost);
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {exception handler } 
                        catch (IOException e) {exception handler }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {exception handler }
```